# Change the default identifier of the type entity in symfony forms

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form which has a field whose type is [entity](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/entity.html).
And by default the values used to identify each entity are database identifiers.

How do I override that? I'd like to use another column which is unique as well.

This is too easy as of `symfony2.7` through `choice_value`, however I'm working on the old `2.3`.

> symfony 2.3 & php5.3

Comment: Do you mean you have a [EntityType field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html)? And what do you mean "default the values used to identify each entity"? Can you post some code to make your question clearer?

Comment: @AlvinBunk yep, updated my post

Comment: Please post some code for a better understanding...

Comment: That sort of stuff is buried deep in the EntityType code.  It actually used the Doctrine metadata to determine which property holds the id for a class.  I don't see any easy way to change it short of maybe extending the type class.  Why do you want to do such a thing?

Comment: I have a form that, when submitted, sends an ajax with POST to an API, and this API does not know database's identifiers but recognizes another (uniq) field

Comment: I have looked around and if you make a custom type extending EntityType and add the same code that they added when implementing the choice_value option  you will be good to go. https://github.com/symfony/doctrine-bridge/blob/master/Form/Type/DoctrineType.php